# Возможно ли упростить процесс присвоения стилей конкретным ячейкам в таблице html?

Tags: html, css

Начал учить HTML/CSS. Пробую создать таблицу умножения. Вроде все создал по [примеру](http://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/computer/multiplication-tables/times-table-12x12.gif), но появился вопрос - можно ли упросить процесс.

Например, чтобы придать стиль для значений по диагонали (в таблице), мне нужно было в каждую конкретную ячейку прописовать класс. Можно ли как-то упростить это, а то если так ячеек не 12, а скажем 50-100, тогда уж очень много рутины добавляется?

Заранее спасибо!
Извините за мою безграмотность если что, я обещаю исправится в скором времени)

P.S. буду благодарен и другим замечаниям по коду.

```css
table {
 width: auto;
 margin: auto;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

caption {
 width: auto;
 font-family: Times, Tahoma, Verdana, serif;
 font-size: 20pt;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #007a4d;
}

th {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 14pt;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffff99;
 width: 30px;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 5px;
}

th.th1 {
 background: none;
}

td {
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 14pt;
 border: 1px solid black;
 text-align: center;
 width: 30px;
 height: 20px;
 padding: 5px;
}

td.td1 {
 border: none;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffff99;
 width: 30px;
 height: 20px;
}

td.td2 {
 background: #ffff99;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align: center;
 background: #ffff99;
 width: 30px;
 height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
<table>
 <caption>Табличка умножения [Вариант 2]</caption>
 <tr>
  <th class="th1"></th>
  <th>1</th>
  <th>2</th>
  <th>3</th>
  <th>4</th>
  <th>5</th>
  <th>6</th>
  <th>7</th>
  <th>8</th>
  <th>9</th>
  <th>10</th>
  <th>11</th>
  <th>12</th>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">1</td>
  <td class="td2">1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>12</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">2</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td class="td2">4</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>24</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">3</td>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td class="td2">9</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>21</td>
  <td>24</td>
  <td>27</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>36</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">4</td>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td class="td2">16</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>24</td>
  <td>28</td>
  <td>32</td>
  <td>36</td>
  <td>40</td>
  <td>44</td>
  <td>48</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">5</td>
  <td>5</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>15</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td class="td2">25</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>35</td>
  <td>40</td>
  <td>45</td>
  <td>50</td>
  <td>55</td>
  <td>60</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">6</td>
  <td>6</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>24</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td class="td2">36</td>
  <td>42</td>
  <td>48</td>
  <td>54</td>
  <td>60</td>
  <td>66</td>
  <td>72</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">7</td>
  <td>7</td>
  <td>14</td>
  <td>21</td>
  <td>28</td>
  <td>35</td>
  <td>42</td>
  <td class="td2">49</td>
  <td>56</td>
  <td>63</td>
  <td>70</td>
  <td>77</td>
  <td>84</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">8</td>
  <td>8</td>
  <td>16</td>
  <td>24</td>
  <td>32</td>
  <td>40</td>
  <td>48</td>
  <td>56</td>
  <td class="td2">64</td>
  <td>72</td>
  <td>80</td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td>96</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">9</td>
  <td>9</td>
  <td>18</td>
  <td>27</td>
  <td>36</td>
  <td>45</td>
  <td>54</td>
  <td>63</td>
  <td>72</td>
  <td class="td2">81</td>
  <td>90</td>
  <td>99</td>
  <td>108</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">10</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>20</td>
  <td>30</td>
  <td>40</td>
  <td>50</td>
  <td>60</td>
  <td>70</td>
  <td>80</td>
  <td>90</td>
  <td class="td2">100</td>
  <td>110</td>
  <td>120</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">11</td>
  <td>11</td>
  <td>22</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>44</td>
  <td>55</td>
  <td>66</td>
  <td>77</td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td>99</td>
  <td>110</td>
  <td class="td2">121</td>
  <td>132</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td class="td1">12</td>
  <td>12</td>
  <td>24</td>
  <td>36</td>
  <td>48</td>
  <td>60</td>
  <td>72</td>
  <td>84</td>
  <td>96</td>
  <td>108</td>
  <td>120</td>
  <td>132</td>
  <td class="td2">144</td>
 </tr>

</table>

</body>
```

Comment: На каком-нибудь  `SCSS` можно было написать что-то типа `@for $i from 2 through 7 {
    tr:nth-child($i) td:nth-child($i + 1) {
        background-color: black;
    }
}` ....а в обычном css автоматизировать вряд ли получится. Только скриптом....... если таблица строится динамически, то тогда там в условии построения строк/столбцов всего лишь надо будет задать условие

Answer (score 2):

Может помочь псевдокласс [nth-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child), если мы говорим о CSS. В частности,  odd (нечетные) и even (четные) номера элементов. Также там можно использовать выражения для более гибкого назначения стилей.

Если вы хотите усложнить поведение каждой отдельной ячейки и сделать это поведение уникальным, то вам понадобится JavaScript.

Comment: А как через `nth-child` прописать диагональ так, чтоб не пришлось писать простыню из `table:nth-child(1) td, table:nth-child(2) td, table:nth-child(3) td ...` и так далее?

Comment: Боюсь, что придётся писать простыню. Так же, может помочь [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195918/css-table-select-cells-on-long-diagonal) тред. Пример в данном там ответе можно переписать на JS и запускать его при загрузке страницы, динамически проставляя классы по диагонали.

Comment: Поэтому ответ с `nth-child` бессмысленнен. Т.к. в данном случае проще каждой ячейке класс присвоить.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский иными словами, Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос.

Comment: Иными словами - не стоит советовать бессмысленные вещи ;-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский или писать бессмысленные комментарии, тем более, что Ваш ответ в оригинальному посту в точности копирует приведенную мной ссылку и текст комментария

Comment: Странно, только комментарий появился на 30 минут раньше вашей ссылки.. мааагия....И собссн поэтому это комментарий, а не ответ, чтоб дать некое направление автору и обратить на этот факт внимание, и, подождать комментарий автора, чтоб узнать - возможно  он это все же динамически делает и можно посоветовать что-то уже на js..Комментарии направляют диалог. А бесполезные ответы без обдумывания - нет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вот это простыня текста =) Ок =)

Comment: Ребята, спасибо за советы и нужное направления.
Пока я только осваиваю html/css и для меня все новое)

Придет время и JS. Тогда и "повоюем" :)

P.S. давайте жить дружно (с)